# VSCode SQL Server extension, no connection

Tags: python, sql-server, visual-studio-code, database-connection

So I am attempting to query data on my Azure SQL database. I have installed the SQL Server extension on VSC and established a connection to my database. On the panel on the left, I can see my connection, my database and the tables I have in my database. I right click on the connection and select 'new query', write my query and then click 'run on active connection'. It then comes up with a pop up from the top saying I have no active connections.

(https://i.stack.imgur.com/acCkA.png)

Why can I not see a connection?

Comment: You can try disconnecting and then reconnecting to the database.

Answer (score 0):

You can check according to the following steps:

1. Ensure that your connection to the Azure SQL database is active.
2. Try disconnecting and then reconnecting to the database.
3. Ensure that your SQL Server instance is running and that you can connect to it from other SQL clients.